# Custom Web Property for CheckBox and Dropdown List SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

i need help regarding the custom web property. I have web part which custom web properties were created for given list url  to the web property. In that we are inserted the image url in the list, this fetches the image to render the webpart.

My question is how we can dynamic the lists to dropdown from the current site and to select the proper list.

Add new webpart properties namely current site checkbox and list dropdown

Thanks Advance
rk